# How to pass encrypted password from one script to another via ssh?

Tags: python, fabric

I'm trying to write a mini script that read a credential file on a local pc, that call another script on a remote machine with the user/password as argument. I'm using Fabric2 to ssh on the remote machine. It all work, but I don't want to send the credential as clear text as it does now. I'd like it to be as secure as possible since I want to implement this in production. Any suggestion ?

The big probleme is on the remote server, if I run ps -ef | grep py I see both username/password clear as argument like this:

> armkreuz 6780 6779 0 15:11 ? 00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3.6
>   /home/armkreuz/scripts/test_password.py fname.lname@exmaple.com
>   test123

```
#Local script
from os.path import expanduser,isfile
from getpass import getpass
import sys
home = expanduser('~')
from fabric import Connection

if not isfile(f"{home}\AppData\Roaming\comcast_credential"):
    user = input('Enter your email adress: ')
    password = getpass("Enter your password: ")
    with open(f"{home}\AppData\Roaming\comcast_credential", 'w') as cred_file:
        cred_file.write(f"{user}\n")
        cred_file.write(password)
else:
    with open(f"{home}\AppData\Roaming\comcast_credential") as cred_file:
        user=cred_file.readline().rstrip('\n')
        password=cred_file.readline()

conn = Connection('armkreuz@192.168.1.188')


if user == "" or password == "":
    print("No user or password")
    exit(0)
print(f"User = {user}")
print(f"Password = {password}")



conn.run(f"/home/armkreuz/scripts/test_password.py {user} {password}")


#Remote script
import sys
from time import sleep

user = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]

with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(f"User = {user}\n")
        file.write(f"Password = {password}")


for x in range(1000):
    print(x)
sleep(10)
```

Comment: You can use symmetric encryption to send the credentials. Have the key on both the server and local PC. Send encrypted credentials from local and decrypt in the remote script.

Comment: Or you can even use asymmetric encryption to send the symmetric key on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to be concerned about this. Passwords should not be given as arguments for this reason.

There's a few ways to pass data over SSH

1. read it in from stdin (your calling script will have to feed details into fabric2)
2. set environment variables from the SSH client. I have no idea if fabric2 supports this. But many servers limit environment variables accepted from a client anyway.
3. send details in a file ahead of time
4. send data in the command

You've gone for the fourth option which has the problem you identified.  I've not tested this myself but the following should work:

```
conn.run(f"PASSWORD='{password}' /home/armkreuz/scripts/test_password.py {user}")
```

Instead of taking the second argument as password you would use an environment variable "`PASSWORD`"

This sends the password in the command (still option 4) but instead of the command passing the password as an argument it is passed it as an environment variable.  Because you set this in the command the SSH server shouldn't block it.

This relays on the syntax of the servers shell (Linux/bash). Note that this may not work for Windows servers.